# Uniformly convergent Fourier serie

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

In my book it says that if F (of causeF'=f) is continuous and piecewise differentiable and if F'=f for all non-break-points then is the Fourier serie for F uniformly convergent. But do F have to be piecewise differentiable and not just differentiable?. Do $F(x)=e^{-x}$, $x\in(-\pi,\pi$) and $F(-\pi)=F(\pi)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{\pi}+e^{-\pi})$ for example have an uniformly convergent Fourier serie on $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: Differentiable implies piece-wise differentiable.

Comment: Thank you it makes sense. So F have an uniformly convergent Fourier serie on  $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ or is there something else wrong?

Comment: If a series or sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly, then the limit must be continuous. Your example is not continuous at $x = \pm \pi$.